# Angular $interval impact if set invokeApply to false

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I got a directive something like below:

```
app.directive('testing', ['$interval', function($interval) {
    return {
        restrict:'E',
        scope: {
            data: '='
        },
        link: function(scope, element) {
            var myInterval = $interval(function() {
                scope.testData = true;
            }, 1000, 0, false);
        },
        templateUrl: 'view/test.html'
    };
}]);
```

In my view/test.html

```
<span ng-if="testData">Showing testData</span>
```

Initially I thought setting invokeApply to false, ng-if will not be fired.

```
var myInterval = $interval(function() {
    scope.testData = true;
}, 1000, 0, false);
```

But regardless of true / false

```
var myInterval = $interval(function() {
    scope.testData = true;
}, 1000, 0, true);
```

scope.testData will still be watched by ng-if.

So my question is, when I set invokeApply to false, what will be the main differences or impact to my app?

Comment: Your thinking is correct.  Setting `invokeApply` to `false` suppresses evaluation via `$rootScope.$evalAsync`.  Can you recreate your issue in plnkr or fiddle?  It seems like there is something else interfering.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/wbdj1tq9/6/ - When setting false, ng-if will still take effect. But after checking out angular source codes for $interval, seems like invokeApply is actually doing $rootScope.$apply. So does it mean parent scope and $rootScope won't be touched?

Comment: `$rootScope.$apply` calls `$rootScope.$digest` which will evaluate all of the watches at `$rootScope` and then will proceed through all child scopes in a depth-first traversal -- so that's everyone.  There is no parent above `$rootScope`.  When `invokeApply` is true, a `$digest` will happen asynchronously.  When it's false, the code will still be run asynchronously, but it won't have a digest.  That's why I think your problem may by some unrelated oversight.